# Rails: Class method scoping on the properties of an associated model

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

This is a somewhat more complicated version of the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28989814/rails-chaining-filter-methods-on-a-model/) I asked previously.

**Background:**

So what I need is to display a list of articles. An article belongs to a media outlet. A media is located in a particular country and publishes articles in a particular language. So the data structure is as follows:

- Article belongs to Media; Media has many Articles
- Media belongs to a Country; Country has many Media
- Media belongs to a Language; Language has many Media

Now, if I wanted to filter articles by media, I could use the following class method (I prefer class methods over scopes, because I am passing a parameter and am using a conditional statement inside the method):

```
  def self.filter_by_media(parameter)
    if parameter == "all"
      all
    else
      where(media_id: parameter)
    end
  end
```

**Question:**

How to write a class method that would filter Articles based by properties of its associated model, the Media? For example, I want to get a list of articles published by media located a certain counrty or in several countries (there is also a default country when the user does not make any choice). Here’s what I tried:

```rb
  # parameter can be either string 'default' or an array of id’s

  def self.filter_by_country(parameter)
    if parameter == "default"
      joins(:media).where(media: [country_id: 1])
    else
      joins(:media).where(media: [country_id: parameter])
    end
  end
```

But that doesn’t work, and I am not conversant enough with SQL to figure out how to make this work. Could you please help?

**Update:**

I’m trying out @carlosramireziii's suggestion. I changed arrays into hashes (don't know what possessed me to use arrays in the first place), but I’m getting the following error in the Rails console (to avoid confusion, in my database, `media` is called `agency`):

```
  def self.filter_by_country(parameter)
    if parameter == "default"
      joins(:agency).where(agency: {country_id: 1})
    else
      joins(:agency).where(agency: {country_id: parameter})
    end
  end

in Rails console:
> Article.filter_by_country('default')

=> Article Load (1.9ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" INNER JOIN "agencies" ON "agencies"."id" = "articles"."agency_id" WHERE "agency"."country_id" = 1
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "agency"
LINE 1: ...ON "agencies"."id" = "articles"."agency_id" WHERE "agency"."...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" INNER JOIN "agencies" ON "agencies"."id" = "articles"."agency_id" WHERE "agency"."country_id" = 1
```

**Update 2**

My mistake in the Update section above is that I did not pluralize `agency` in the `where` clause. The part `where(agency: {country_id: 1})` should have read `where(agencies: {country_id: 1})`. The pluralized word `agencies` here refers to the name of the table that is being joined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close, you just need to use a nested hash instead of an array.

Try this

```
def self.filter_by_country(parameter)
   if parameter == "default"
      joins(:media).where(media: { country_id: 1 })
   else
      joins(:media).where(media: { country_id: parameter })
   end
end
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense, but when I try this function in the Rails console I’m getting an error (see the Update section of my question).

Comment: Oh, I think I got it. In my case, instead of `media` I used `agency`, and the word `agency` in the nested hash should apparently have been pluralized (`joins(:agency).where(agencies: { country_id: 1 })`).

Comment: Yay, totally working after pluralization of `agencies`. Checked it in the Rails console :-)

Comment: Ah just saw this. Yes you need to pluralize it inside the where clause because you are referring to the _table_ name (which is always plural), not the association name. Glad you got it working!